# How do I turn CPT automatically also into category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

When I create a new post on a CPT I want to automatically turn it also into a category to appear in another CPT.
Example: I have a post type called "School Subject" and when I create the subject "Math" it will appear as category on the CPT called "Exams"

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Abhik I know how to do it manually, creating the category on functions.php using ` register_taxonomy_for_object_type('cat', 'CPT');`. I wantted to make something that when I add a post, it could pull the function that create a category

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom callback to the `save_post_{$post->post_type}` action, which fires after the defined type of post has been saved. (*Use your CPT name in the place of the curly brackets placeholder*) The callback recieves the saved post as its second parameter, ID being the first, from which you can get appropriate details (namely the title) for `wp_insert_term()` which you'd use for adding the new term.

The callback recieves boolean value as the third parameter, which tells you, if the save happens for a new post or an existing one, i.e. is an update. You should utilize this to prevent your callback from creating a new term every time the action is fired, but only for new posts.

Check out the docs, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term/, for more details on how to use the action and the function.

*P.s. I'm sorry for not adding a code example. Adding one now is a bit difficult as I'm typing this on a mobile device.*